# Unable to SSH/Ping to VMs on Private Network of Openstack/packstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, rdo

We are using a setup of Openstack-Train through a Packstack installation and Openvswitch as the backend of neutron.

We have created an external network (10.5.0.0/22), which is an internal network of our org. and an private network (10.3.0.0/22) linked via a router.

Our org. network is connected with a Pfsense firewall which has been given permission to connect the network 10.5.0.0/22 to 10.3.0.0/22 of openstack and vice versa.

In the security group of openstack, we have added the egress and ingress rule to allow traffic between the two networks.

However, we are unable to ping or SSH any VMs that are built on the private network (10.3.0.0/22) from our org. network (10.5.0.0/22).

VMs on the private network have internet connectivity and can ping google and ssh into our org. machines that are on the 10.5.0.0/22 ip range.

The only way to SSH into private network VMs seem to via a floating IP.

Is there a way to directly SSH into the private network VMs without using the floating IP?
Or is this part of openstack design?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any physical network hardware like Switches that are configured to only allow a specific VLAN or subnet traffic?

Can you also share how your subnet is configured "openstack subnet show"

Security does isolate traffic outside a subnet so floating IP is alternative way in, but it's possible to have multiple ports on a vm with different subnets and access.

Comment: Do you have any physical network hardware like Switches that are configured to only allow a specific VLAN or subnet traffic? - No

Here are the subnets and their details-
https://imgur.com/fdjjjuz
https://imgur.com/mN47koB
https://imgur.com/vGKZPNm